# mongodb replica sync alway fails

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-replica-set

I have a MongoDB replica set. I periodically put a lot of data into the master (like 1T); every time, all the secondary nodes enter "recovering" status and never come back.

I already increased the binlog size to a very large value; is there any panacea configuration that can solve this problem?

Comment: Can I ask two points of clarification; when you say _binlog_, do you mean the [oplog](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-oplog/)? Secondly, have you checked the secondary servers' logs to see exactly why they say they're entering 'recovering' status?

Comment: Yes, I mean oplog, sorry for the ambiguity. The secondary nodes log says "we are too stale to use xxxx as a sync source". It just looks like that the rsync is not fast enough when we pushing the large amount of data into the primary. Not sure if there is a configuration like delay sync to solve this problem.